# Weighted flow accumulation with pygeoprocessing

Tags: flow-accumulation, pygeoprocessing

I cannot manage to get results for a weighted flow accumulation with pygeoproccessing. When I try it without the weight, it does work. However, I need the weight and when I include it, python just stays in calculation mode forever without useful results. It does create a raster file for the flow accumulation, but without accumulation results. Also, there is no error message in the python console. One time, I let it continue a whole night and nothing more came out.

I prepared the dem in QGIS with fill sinks (saga) and unified extent and resolution of the dem and the weight raster with QGIS raster calculator, so the dimensions of the datasets are the same.

I have tried it with data for a complete basin, but also with a small clipped test area. The same problem occurs.

My code (working in anaconda, spyder, python 3.7):

```
#load module
import pygeoprocessing.routing as geop

#define test data locations
path = "C:/test/"
dem = "{}dem_clip.tif".format(path)
flow_dir = "{}flodir.tif".format(path)
ro = "{}ro_clip.tif".format(path)
flow_acc =  "{}flowacc.tif".format(path)

# calculate flow directions
geop.flow_dir_d8((dem,1),flow_dir)

# accumulate 
geop.flow_accumulation_d8((flow_dir,1), flow_acc, (ro,1))
```

I usually do the weighted flow accumulation with saga (in QGIS/R), which works, but since im running into issues with larger datasets I am trying to explore other ways. That is the reason I am trying pygeoprocessing.

Does anybody know what can be the issue?